# Redis is seeing legitimate connections as attacks - possibly due to reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm running Redis for use with Rails and Action Cable. These all sit behind an Nginx reverse proxy. Currently whenever Redis is connected to, I get

```
# Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
```

Is it possible the Nginx setup is causing this? Here is the config if so:

```
server {
       server_name "###";
                                                                                                                                                                                    location / {                                                                                                                                                                          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;                                                                                                                                            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;                                                                                                                                        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        }
        location /cable {                                                                                                                                                                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6379;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                                                                                                                 proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;                                                                                                                                        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;                                                                                                                             proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/###/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/###/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}server {
    if ($host = ###) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


       listen 80;
       server_name "###";
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "whenever Redis is connected to"? What is connecting to Redis? In what manner?